# How to interrupt a running Batch file, execute a command in its environment, then continue?

Tags: windows, batch

I'm aware that I can interrupt a running batch file witch Crtl-C, and then continue the execution.

However, is it possible to execute a command in the batch file's cmd environment while the batch is paused?

For example, I might want to pause a running batch, change some variables it has SET previously, then continue the execution.

Comment: add lines with modifications (i.e. set new value to the variable) after pause and continue the batch

Comment: such a simple solution! :) unfortunately, can't select comment as answer

Comment: @jet: How would one continue execution of the batch file where it left off (i.e. right after the `pause` command)?

Comment: @vedran: I added it as an answer

Comment: @martineau: before pause, put command.com for example... and then you know... exit and you are back to the batch, maybe there is a better way

Comment: @jet: Actually it's `cmd.exe` nowadays. In your scheme, control will pass to another instance of the shell and any changes made to environment variable there be lost when it is `exit`ed. Then the `pause` command would be encountered which will just display `Press any key to continue ...` all off which I don't think is what the OP seeks.

Comment: but you modify env. variables not interactively, but as lines inside your batch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add lines in the batch with modifications (i.e. set new value to the variable) after pause and continue the batch

Answer (score 3):

This code will allow to execute arbitrary commands from within batch context: 
Put it a batch file and play with it.

```
@echo off

:loop 
  set cmd=
  set /p "cmd=Please give command, empty line to finish "
  if defined cmd (
    call %cmd%
    goto loop
  )
```

To finish executing commands just hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>

To use it in your batch, just insert a line with call to above:

```
do stuff 
do more stuff

call interrupt_me.bat

do even more stuff
```

If you wonder why there is a `call %cmd%` instead of straight `%cmd%` - it allows to expand variables passed so commands like `echo %comspec%` work properly.